# Javascript frames function only works on compatibility mode

Tags: javascript, frames, compatibility-mode

I guess I don't understand what changes with compatibility mode in IE11, and I just had a general idea of how it works. The following function works fine on compatibility mode:

```
this.messageBody = frames["messageEditor___Frame"].frames[0].document.body.innerHTML;
```

But it fails to assign a value without compatibility switched on. I used try/catch to fin the error messaged which prompted to:

```
> Unable to get frames property of undefined or null reference.
```

I would appreciate if someone could fill me in on the changes that javascript goes through when compatibility mode is switched on/off.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know the IE11. Is there a console which can log browsable/inspectable objects? Investigate frames["..."] as well as window.frames. My ideas are: The global context isn't window; there's no "messageEditor___Frame" property name allowed or transscripted from HTML input - maybe due to case(in)sensitivity or underscores.

Comment: I guess it may have something to do with the `<frameset>` tag being unsupported in HTML5? - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp

Comment: I've assumed that an appropriate doctype is used and frames are displayed correct while only the javascript fails.
Some more complete and reproducable code example should be posted.

Comment: It was due to the frameset tag not being supported by HTML5